# attach the database in memory to database in disk

Tags: python-3.x, memory-management, sqlite

Good evening, I would like to attach a database created in memory with database created and saved on the disk. I reached the first part (create the DB in memory) but I have difficults to attach it with DB on the disk.

```
import sqlite3
# set up a database in memory
c = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
c.execute('CREATE TABLE my_table (id int, name text);')
c.execute("INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (1, 'bruce'), (2, 'wayne'), (3, 'bat');")
c.commit()
```

I tried this code below but it doesn't work :/ :

```
ATTACH DATABASE 'file::memory:?cache=shared' AS db_disk
```

Comment: `:memory:` and `file::memory:?cache=shared` are two different databases. And why are you calling it `db_disk` when it's an in-memory DB?

Comment: I thought this mean take in memory database and put it in db_disk, but i suppose this is wrong :/, so, how can I merge the database in memory with the database in disk. 
by the way my final goal is to speed up the writting on a db, this is why I use the concept of :memory:

Comment: Attaching, by itself, does not write anything. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I start by scrape a web site after I would like to save data in a database.
I am trying to improve the performance of writing on a database.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, there is no direct way to copy the contents of an in-memory database to disk.

But the database forces writes to disk only when a transaction commits, so you can get the same speed by using a disk database and writing everything in a single transaction, i.e., by *not* calling `commit()` before you are finished.
(But you might want to increase the [cache size](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_cache_size).)